# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in multiple Browsers on multiple Networks

Tags: php, google-chrome

I'm a web developer and currently working on an internet project for my company.
I've been working on this for nearly 2 years now.

I work on a MacBook Pro with MacOSX 10.9.1 and debug and test the project mainly with Chrome 31.0.1650.63
The intranet is developed with a PHP backend, so the problem might be PHP related

Here's my problem:

When I visit the dev version of the intranet I randomly get an 101 ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Error.
It happens on different browser and different conenctions.

What I tried so far:

- Testing in multiple browsers: Firefox 26.0 and Safari 7.0.1
- Testing on multiple connections LAN, WLAN and 3G (all seperate providers)
- Clearing the cache and the cookies of these 3 browsers and trying again
- Testing the site in incognito mode, so all the extensions are out of the picture
- Starting chrome with the flags "--enable-logging --v=1" to see if the chrome logs give me some insights
- Reading through the error log of the webserver for anything suspicious

I think this is the line in the chrome log when the error occurs:

[25524:1799:0113/140554:VERBOSE1:web_contents_impl.cc(2267)] Failed Provisional Load: #IntranetURL#, error_code: -101, error_description: Connection reset., is_main_frame: 1, showing_repost_interstitial: 0, frame_id: 1

There is one strange line in the error_log of the webserver:

[Fri Jan 10 23:57:07 2014] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: #PathToOurWebspace#/system-error

A colleague suggested, that this might be a error handler specified in the vhost config. We created the file but it makes no difference. This line is found all over the place in the error log.

The rest are just PHP ParseErrors or FatalErrors from fcgi, but those shouldn't be the problem right? I should at least see the php error output in the browser like all the other php errors, right?

Thanks for reading this and for any help!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this the solution in my case was the following:

I use the PeriodicalUpdate Port by RobertFischer (https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater) in m project.

This jquery plugin sets cookies with the milliseconds of the last call.
If no cookie name is specified in the plugin config it uses the URL of the origin of the call as default.

And as far as my understanding goes - everytime I navigated to another page this created a new cookie because of the new URL.

I don't know exactly how this can be the fix, but if i delete the cookies created by the periodical updater and disable cookies at all in the plugin config, the problem is gone.

Might be a bug in the PeriodicalUpdater port, or in the jQuery Cookie plugin by Klaus Hartl (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) which is used to write the cookies.

This is my current PeriodicalUpdater call (i create these via php):

```
$.PeriodicalUpdater($handler, {
        method: 'get', 
        data: newParams,
        minTimeout: $minTimeout,
        maxTimeout: $maxTimeout,
        multiplier: $multiplier,
        type: $type,
        maxCalls: $maxCalls,
        autoStop: $autoStop,
        autoStopCallback: function(){$autoStopCallback},
        cookie: false,
        verbose: $verbose
    }
);
```