# How to gracefully handle exceeded execution time (timeout) in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

If I try to upload a very large file in WordPress which is ~ 100 mb in file size, the `max_execution_time` in PHP is reached and I get a browser-styled error page which reads:

> This webpage is not available
>
> The connection to example.com was interrupted
>
> Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Is there a way I can detect when the execution time has been reached and display my own custom error message in place of the default error message I am getting?

Comment: set `upload_max_filesize` to something smaller so you can catch the error before php dies.

Comment: I'll do that in the php.ini. But then how would I catch the error?

Comment: See second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567861/detect-if-uploaded-file-is-too-large

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PHP's `set_time_limit()` function when appropriate:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: thanks for this! I'm wondering if it's a good idea to remove the time limit from a script? Couldn't that result in a performance issue - especially if people leave their browser window open?

Comment: Well, not really, since the script *will* eventually end, and you don't want it to end with an error. If a user is uploading a 100MB file, I'd gather he'll be willing to wait until the server responds somehow.

Comment: Good point about the script eventually ending! I just tried `set_time_limit(0)` in my script and still got the error `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` which makes me think this might not be due to PHP timing out? I'll need to investigate more. Thanks for your help

Comment: Google it a bit more, I think. Perhaps it might be this or something else in SO already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092681/err-connection-reset-in-multiple-browsers-on-multiple-networks